# Find the solution to a PDE with an initial condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Find the solution to $u_x + y u_y = u$ with initial condition $u(0,y) = \cos(y)$.

Attempted solution - Suppose we parametrize a curve $(x,y)$ by a parameter $\xi$. So that

$$
u=u(x(\xi),y(\xi))
$$

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}\xi}=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\xi}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}\xi}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
$$

Comparing to our original PDE

$$
u = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
$$

We then set

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}\xi}=u
$$

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\xi}=1
$$

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}\xi}=y
$$

We then have

$$
\mathrm{d}\xi=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u}= \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y}
$$

Integrating we have $$\xi = \ln(u) = x = \ln(y) + C$$

Now for the general solution we have $$\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}\xi} = u \Rightarrow \mathrm{d}\xi = \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u}\Rightarrow \xi = \ln(u) + C \Rightarrow u = Ce^{\xi}$$

The initial condition implies...

I am following the structure from another user that answered a similar question I had but I am now a bit lost applying the initial condition. I do know that $x = \xi$ but I am not sure how to get the rest of the solution from there.

Comment: $\frac{dx}{d\xi}$ should be 1.

Comment: @CheeHan Thank you just caught that

Comment: You set up the correct characteristic equations. Now you need to paramaterise your "initial curve", i.e the curve traced out by the given initial condition. These will serve as the initial condition for the characteristic equations. Since $u(0,y) = \cos(y)$, you may parameterise your initial curve as $x(0) = 0, y(0)=s, u(0,s)=\cos(s)$. Now solve each of the three characteristic equation with respective initial condition.

Comment: @CheeHan I see, but don't I need to find the general solution first and then apply the initial condition? I believe after my last line I wrote I need to integrate to get $\xi = \ln(u) = x = \ln(y) + C$?

Comment: Your answer will then be in terms of $\xi$ and $s$ and the trick now is to try and express $\xi$ and $s$ in terms of $x$ and $y$. Not that this is not always possible.

Comment: I see nothing like this. This is what I saw from your post: "I am following the structure from another user that answered a similar question I had but I am bit lost at this point finding the general solution to this PDE. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated." You are correct, the general solution is obtained by solving the first order ODEs that you written down, and the constant is found by using the initial condition that I just mentioned.

Comment: @CheeHan I am not sure I am following what you mean by saying "I see nothing like this. This is what I saw from your post"...

Comment: I was saying that your post didn't say anything that you said: "I need to integrate to get .................", but you just edited your post again so that is fine.

Comment: @CheeHan Ok, I understand now. My apologies I am a bit lost, I haven't formally taken differential equations before so I am very slow in solving and understanding these type of problems in PDE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59089/discussion-between-chee-han-and-wolfy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u_x+yu_y=u$$
Set of characteristic ODEs: $\quad \frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{u}$

First family of characteristics curves, from $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{y} \quad\to\quad ye^{-x}=c_1$

Second family of characteristics curves, from $\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{u} \quad\to\quad \frac{u}{y}=c_2$

General solution, with any differentiable fonction $F$ :
$$\frac{u}{y}=F(ye^{-x}) \quad\to\quad u=y\:F(ye^{-x}) $$
Condition : $\quad u(0,y)=\cos(y)=y\:F(ye^{0}) \quad$ determines the function $F$ :

$$F(t)=\frac{\cos(t)}{t} \quad \text{any } t\neq 0$$

Bringing this function $F$ into the above general solution gives 
$\quad u=y\:\frac{\cos(ye^{-x}) )}{ye^{-x}}$
$$u(x,y)=e^x\cos(y\:e^{-x})$$

Comment: Can you explain why $F(t) = \frac{cos(t)}{t}$ comes from? I don't understand that part

Comment: From $\quad \cos(y)=y\:F(ye^{0})=y\:F(y)\quad $; Hence $\quad F(y)=\frac{\cos(y)}{y}\quad $. This defines the fonction $F$. The variable of a function can be represented by any symbol. So you can replace $y$ by any symbol, for example by $t$ or any other if you prefer.